# Displaying questions from API one at a time in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

i want to display the questions i get from an API one by one. I call the API, parse and store the data, but i don't know how to display each question separately. I can put them in a list view but that's about it. I have a widget with FutureBuilder that calls the API, and i'm currently trying to send data to another widget and manipulate it there using another FutureBuilder (so that i don't keep calling the API when i iterate through the list of questions to display them). I have an integer to keep track of the current position. How should i go about doing this?

Part of the code:
Here i'm trying to send the data to another widget.

```
FutureBuilder<Reply>(
              future: questions(token, id),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  print('Error : ${snapshot.error}'); //show error on the terminal
                  return Text('Error : ${snapshot.error}'); //show error on the app
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  reply = snapshot.data;
                  return Show_Questions(reply: reply,);
                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); //else display a loading indicator
                } //loading indicator
              }
          ),
```

Any help is appreciated. I can post more code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new FutureBuilder(
          future: questions(token, id),
          initialData: [],
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return createListView(context, snapshot);
          }),
    );

  }

  Widget createListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    var values = snapshot.data;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: values == null ? 0 : values.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {

            });
          },
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new ListTile(
                title: Text(values[index]),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 2.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

hopefully help you :)

Comment: Thank you for replying! Sorry if i wasn't very clear but i want to display each question on a different screen. So it will be like first screen: "How do you feel about A?", second screen: "What do you think about B?", and so on.